# What are the half-moons in the HUD in Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time?

Tags: prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time

As you can see here:

[image: the interface]

There is an hourglass-like vertical counter of sand that represents how much charge you have for the Dagger of Time. Alongside that hourglass counter is a series of half moons that are either empty or filled up white. In the image I've linked above, that counter is half full.

What does the half moon counter represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called power tanks, which you need for certain special abilities.

> The white crescent symbols next to the Sand Tanks indicate your Power
>   Tanks. Shove your dagger into sixteen enemies and Retrieve their sand
>   to add another Power Tank (you can't have more than ten). Most of your
>   special moves require energy from the Power Tank.

[Source](https://www.ign.com/wikis/prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time/Basics)